# In which case a object holds the default lock(monitor lock)

Tags: java

In which case a object holds the default lock(monitor lock) ?
I am little bit confused that if there is any concept of default lock in java synchronization.
So if any one help me out.

Comment: The question isn't clear enough. Remember that a thread holds a monitor; there's no concept of an object holding it. Also, what do you mean by "default lock"?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding...
But my question was -- is java Maintains any default lock on any object  internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It is a thread that can hold a lock, not an object. See java.lang.Thread.holdsLock API *This method is designed to allow a program to assert that the current thread already holds a specified lock*

2) There is a notion of implicit locks in Java, there is no default lock